# How tell tell if a number changes on a website - Python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have got some stocks and I thought it would be a good idea to make it so if my stock rises to a certain value I get an email notification, I know to to send an email using python and I understand the very basics of BeautifulSoup and I have seen questions that tell me how to tell if a website changes, but as this is stocks It would change a lot... any help would be appreciated...

This is my current code if anyone is interested:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
page = requests.get("http://www.londonstockexchange.com/exchange/portfolio/summary.html#/trading-simulator/308259")
page
url = "http://www.londonstockexchange.com/exchange/portfolio/summary.html#/trading-simulator/308259"
values = {'***': 'user', #not going to give away my username and password
    '***': 'pass'}
requests.session()
requests.post(url, data=values)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
print(soup.prettify())
```

Comment: "I have seen questions that tell me how to tell if a website changes, but as this is stocks It would change a lot". Ok, but those answers will still work regardless of how often the page changes, wouldn't they? If not, why not?

Comment: You need to deal with logging in. This may be more complicated than you're willing to take on.

Comment: @kevin Every time the website changes I don't want to receive an email, also I don't mind dealing with logging in so long as i don't have to download loads of stuff

Comment: I mentioned logging in because you'll need to do it from your script, process the cookie, etc. I've never done it myself, but I would expect it to be more complicated than you'll be willing to do.

Comment: Please add at least a sample of the HTML content of the site you want to observer and we can try to create a work around. You can't expect people to have an account there thus we can't help you.

Comment: Ok i would still like to try, @Kevin in answer to your question, i want it to email every time my stock reaches a certain value... it also says in the question

Comment: @datell if you run the code in the question it shows the HTML content, if it is not enough i can show the HTML content from the page in the answer

Comment: If I visit the url shown in your code I get to a login site. I don't expect there to be any difference just by sending a HTTP Get using a Python library instead of my webbrowser...But we can observe the login site if you want to ;)

Comment: Oh, when I run it it shows a bunch of html code, I am afraid I don't understand the second bit of your comment

Comment: If you want to login you should use requests.session(), then post your credentials and then get your page.

Comment: do you mean user name and password...

Comment: Yes. Try sending this post data : { 'j_username' : Your Username, 'j_password' : Your password }

Comment: Now you got the login part, edit your question and add the HTML content and we can talk about parsing.

Comment: ok, may be a minute or two while I type out the code

Comment: @t.m.adam where do i enter my user name and password? i ried this requests.session('username', password) with my actual username and password but it wouldn't work

Comment: @datell sorry for the wait, the user name part won't work

Comment: Use requests.session() as your requests object : `http = requests.session()` , then post your data with it : `login = http.post(yourpage, data=yourdata)`,  then get your page : `page = http.get(yourpage)`

Comment: @datell it now works will add my code to my question

Comment: @t.m.adam Have done it now

Comment: Thank you for editing you question. But since I don't have (and don't want) your login data I still can't see the content. Please just get the HTML content and add it or create a pastebin and add a link to it.

Comment: ok, sorry about the delay had to go do something

Comment: will add the code once i have the relevant art, theres quite a lot...

Comment: @datell there is so much code (over 57000 lines) I can't find the right bit, do you know if theres a fast way to do so? also theres too much to post in a question

Comment: Have found a way to do it thanks for all the help